# How to pass the data from the form to the next screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an application that has a pretty long form with a lot of text fields, so I divided the text fields into multiple screens. It got three screens, the first screen has some common text fields such as phone, website, email, etc. The second screen has some more text fields and the same with the third screen. I'm trying to display all the details from the three forms at the end on a different screen.

[image: First screen]

[image]

[image]

I want to display all the details in the end when I hit the 'Done' button on a different page.

Here's the code for the first screen which has the first form:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/model.dart';
import 'package:validators/validators.dart' as validator;
import 'package:instaskool/home_screens/homescreen_student.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/home_screens/homescreen_school.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/screens/school_signup_two.dart';



class SchoolReg extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SchoolRegState createState() => _SchoolRegState();
}
class _SchoolRegState extends State<SchoolReg> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  School school = School();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(


  body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new Form(

          key: _formKey,

          child: Column(

            children: <Widget>[

              Container(

                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 130),
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,


    child:  MyTextFormField(

                        hintText: 'School name',

                        validator: (String value) {

                          if (value.isEmpty) {

                            return 'Enter your school name';

                          }

                          return null;

                        },

                        onSaved: (String value) {

                          school.schoolName = value;

                        },

                      ),


              ),


                  MyTextFormField(

                        hintText: 'Phone',

                        validator: (String value) {

                          if (value.isEmpty) {

                            return 'Enter the phone number';

                          }

                          return null;

                        },

                        onSaved: (String value) {

                          school.schoolPhone = value;

                        },
                  ),


                   MyTextFormField(

                        hintText: 'Email',

                        validator: (String value) {

                          if (value.isEmpty) {

                            return 'Enter the email address';

                          }

                          return null;

                        },

                        onSaved: (String value) {

                          school.schoolEmail = value;

                        },

                      ),


            MyTextFormField(
                hintText: 'School Website',

                isEmail: true,

                validator: (String value) {

                  if (value.isEmpty) {

                    return "Enter the school's website";

                  }

                  return null;

                },

                onSaved: (String value) {

                  school.schoolWebsite = value;

                },

              ),



              RaisedButton(

                color: Colors.blueAccent,



                onPressed: () {

                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                    _formKey.currentState.save();

    Navigator.push(

                        context,

                        MaterialPageRoute(

                            builder: (context) => SchoolRegTwo()));

                  }

                },

                child: Text(

                  'Next',

                  style: TextStyle(

                    color: Colors.white,

                  ),

                ),

              )

            ],

          ),

        ),
  ),
);
  }
}
class MyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final Function validator;
  final Function onSaved;
  final bool isPassword;
  final bool isEmail;
MyTextFormField({
    this.hintText,
    this.validator,
    this.onSaved,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.isEmail = false,
  });
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        ),
        obscureText: isPassword ? true : false,
        validator: validator,
        onSaved: onSaved,
        keyboardType: isEmail ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the code for the second form:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/model.dart';
import 'package:validators/validators.dart' as validator;
import 'package:instaskool/home_screens/homescreen_student.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/home_screens/homescreen_school.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/screens/school_signup_three.dart';


class SchoolRegTwo extends StatefulWidget {



  @override
  _SchoolRegTwoState createState() => _SchoolRegTwoState();
}
class _SchoolRegTwoState extends State<SchoolRegTwo> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  SchoolDet schooldet = SchoolDet();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(


  body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new Form(

          key: _formKey,

          child: Column(

            children: <Widget>[

              Container(

                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 130),
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,


    child:  MyTextFormField(

                        hintText: 'School address 1',

                        validator: (String value) {

                          if (value.isEmpty) {

                            return "Enter your school's address";

                          }

                          return null;

                        },

                        onSaved: (String value) {

                          schooldet.addressOne = value;

                        },

                      ),


              ),


                  MyTextFormField(

                        hintText: 'School address 2',

                        validator: (String value) {

                          if (value.isEmpty) {

                            return "Enter the school's address";

                          }

                          return null;

                        },

                        onSaved: (String value) {

                          schooldet.addressTwo = value;

                        },
                  ),


                   MyTextFormField(

                        hintText: 'City',

                        validator: (String value) {

                          if (value.isEmpty) {

                            return 'Enter the city';

                          }

                          return null;

                        },

                        onSaved: (String value) {

                          schooldet.city = value;

                        },

                      ),


            MyTextFormField(
                hintText: 'Pincode',

                isEmail: true,

                validator: (String value) {

                  if (value.isEmpty) {

                    return "Enter the pincode";

                  }

                  return null;

                },

                onSaved: (String value) {

                  schooldet.pincode = value;

                },

              ),




            MyTextFormField(
                hintText: 'State',

                isEmail: true,

                validator: (String value) {

                  if (value.isEmpty) {

                    return "Enter the state";

                  }

                  return null;

                },

                onSaved: (String value) {

                  schooldet.state = value;

                },

              ),


              RaisedButton(

                color: Colors.blueAccent,

                onPressed: () {

                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                    _formKey.currentState.save();

    Navigator.push(

                        context,

                        MaterialPageRoute(

                            builder: (context) => SchoolRegThree(schooldet: this.schooldet)));

                  }

                },

                child: Text(

                  'Next',

                  style: TextStyle(

                    color: Colors.white,

                  ),

                ),

              )

            ],

          ),

        ),
  ),
);
  }
}
class MyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final Function validator;
  final Function onSaved;
  final bool isPassword;
  final bool isEmail;
MyTextFormField({
    this.hintText,
    this.validator,
    this.onSaved,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.isEmail = false,
  });
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        ),
        obscureText: isPassword ? true : false,
        validator: validator,
        onSaved: onSaved,
        keyboardType: isEmail ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the code for the third form:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/model.dart';
import 'package:validators/validators.dart' as validator;
import 'package:instaskool/home_screens/homescreen_student.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/home_screens/homescreen_school.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/screens/school_signup_three.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/screens/school_code.dart';


class SchoolRegThree extends StatefulWidget {

   School school;
   SchoolRegThree({this.school, SchoolDet schooldet});

  @override
  _SchoolRegThreeState createState() => _SchoolRegThreeState();
}
class _SchoolRegThreeState extends State<SchoolRegThree> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  SchoolUser schooluser = SchoolUser();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(


  body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new Form(

          key: _formKey,

          child: Column(

            children: <Widget>[

              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                  child: MyTextFormField(


                  hintText: 'Username',

                  isPassword: true,

                  validator: (String value) {

                    if (value.length < 5) {

                      return 'Username should be at least 5 characters long';

                    }

    _formKey.currentState.save();

    return null;

                  },

                  onSaved: (String value) {

                    schooluser.username = value;

                  },

                ),
              ),

              MyTextFormField(

                hintText: 'New Password',

                isPassword: true,

                validator: (String value) {

                  if (value.length < 7) {

                    return 'Password should be at least 7 characters long';

                  } else if (schooluser.password != null) {

                    print(value);

                    print(schooluser.password);


                  }

    return null;

                },

                onSaved: (String value) {

                  schooluser.password = value;

                },

              ),

              RaisedButton(

                color: Colors.blueAccent,

                onPressed: () {

                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                    _formKey.currentState.save();

    Navigator.push(

                        context,

                        MaterialPageRoute(

                            builder: (context) => ResultSchool(schooluser: this.schooluser)));

                  }

                },

                child: Text(

                  'Done',

                  style: TextStyle(

                    color: Colors.white,

                  ),

                ),

              )

            ],

          ),

        ),
  ),
);
  }
}
class MyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final Function validator;
  final Function onSaved;
  final bool isPassword;
  final bool isEmail;
MyTextFormField({
    this.hintText,
    this.validator,
    this.onSaved,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.isEmail = false,
  });
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        ),
        obscureText: isPassword ? true : false,
        validator: validator,
        onSaved: onSaved,
        keyboardType: isEmail ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the model.dart which has all the variables:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/screens/school_code.dart';

class Model {
  String fullname;
  String code;
  String standard;
  String section;
  String username;
  String password;
Model({this.fullname, this.code, this.standard, this.section, this.username, this.password});
}

class School {
  String schoolName;
  String schoolPhone;
  String schoolEmail;
  String schoolWebsite;
  School({this.schoolName, this.schoolPhone, this.schoolEmail, this.schoolWebsite});

}

class SchoolDet {
  String addressOne;
  String addressTwo;
  String city;
  String pincode;
  String state;

    SchoolDet({this.addressOne, this.addressTwo, this.city, this.pincode, this.state});

}

class SchoolUser{
  String username;
  String password;

  SchoolUser({this.username, this.password});
}

class SchoolCode{
  String principalCode;
  String teacherCode;
  String studentCode;

SchoolCode({this.principalCode, this.teacherCode, this.studentCode});
}
```

Here's the result screen where I wanna display all the data:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instaskool/model.dart';

class ResultSchool extends StatelessWidget {
 School school;
 SchoolDet schooldet;
 SchoolCode schoolcode;
 SchoolUser schooluser;
 ResultSchool({this.school, this.schooldet, this.schooluser});
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('School details')),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(school.schoolName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(school.schoolPhone, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(school.schoolEmail, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(school.schoolWebsite, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(schooldet.addressOne, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(schooldet.addressTwo, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(schooldet.city, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(schooldet.pincode, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(schooldet.state, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),

            Text(schooluser.username, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(schooluser.password, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),

            Text(schoolcode.teacherCode, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            Text(schoolcode.principalCode, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a widget to manage form transitions

```
enum SchoolFormPhase { BASIC_DTL, ADDRESS, USER_DTL }


class SchoolRegistration extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SchoolRegistrationState createState() => _SchoolRegistrationState();
}

class _SchoolRegistrationState extends State<SchoolRegistration> {
  SchoolFormPhase phase;
  School schoolForm;

  @override
  void initState() {
    phase = SchoolFormPhase.BASIC_DTL;
    schoolForm = School();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (phase) {
      case SchoolFormPhase.BASIC_DTL:
        return SchoolReg(
            school: schoolForm,
            onSaved: (school) {
              setState(() {
                schoolForm = school;
                phase = SchoolFormPhase.ADDRESS;
              });
            });

      case SchoolFormPhase.ADDRESS:
        return SchoolRegTwo(
            school: schoolForm,
            onSaved: (school) {
              setState(() {
                schoolForm = school;
                phase = SchoolFormPhase.USER_DTL;
              });
            });

      case SchoolFormPhase.USER_DTL:
        return SchoolRegThree(
          school: schoolForm,
          onSaved: (school) {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ResultSchool(
                        schooluser: school.user,
                        school: school,
                        schooldet: school.address)));
          },
        );
    }
    return Container();
  }
}
```

change the Form widget to accept inputs

```
class SchoolReg extends StatefulWidget {
  final School school;
  final Function(School) onSaved;

  const SchoolReg({Key key, this.school, this.onSaved}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SchoolRegState createState() => _SchoolRegState();
}

class _SchoolRegState extends State<SchoolReg> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  School _school;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _school = widget.school;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 130),
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: MyTextFormField(
                          hintText: 'School name',
                          validator: (String value) {
                            return value.isEmpty
                                ? 'Enter your school name'
                                : null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) => _school.schoolName = value)),
                  MyTextFormField(
                    hintText: 'Phone',
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Enter the phone number';
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      _school.schoolPhone = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  MyTextFormField(
                    hintText: 'Email',
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Enter the email address';
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      _school.schoolEmail = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  MyTextFormField(
                    hintText: 'School Website',
                    isEmail: true,
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return "Enter the school's website";
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      _school.schoolWebsite = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          _formKey.currentState.save();
                          widget.onSaved(_school);
                        }
                      },
                      child:
                          Text('Next', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))
                ]))));
  }
}
```

form 2

```
class SchoolRegTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  final School school;
  final Function(School) onSaved;

  const SchoolRegTwo({Key key, this.school, this.onSaved}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SchoolRegTwoState createState() => _SchoolRegTwoState();
}

class _SchoolRegTwoState extends State<SchoolRegTwo> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  SchoolDet schooldet;

  @override
  void initState() {
    schooldet = widget.school.address;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 130),
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: MyTextFormField(
                      hintText: 'School address 1',
                      validator: (String value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return "Enter your school's address";
                        }

                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (String value) {
                        schooldet.addressOne = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  MyTextFormField(
                    hintText: 'School address 2',
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return "Enter the school's address";
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      schooldet.addressTwo = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  MyTextFormField(
                    hintText: 'City',
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Enter the city';
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      schooldet.city = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  MyTextFormField(
                    hintText: 'Pincode',
                    isEmail: true,
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return "Enter the pincode";
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      schooldet.pincode = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  MyTextFormField(
                    hintText: 'State',
                    isEmail: true,
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return "Enter the state";
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      schooldet.state = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          _formKey.currentState.save();
                          widget.school.address = schooldet;
                          widget.onSaved(widget.school);
                        }
                      },
                      child:
                          Text('Next', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))
                ]))));
  }
}
```

form 3

```
class SchoolRegThree extends StatefulWidget {
  School school;
  final Function(School) onSaved;

  SchoolRegThree({this.school, this.onSaved});

  @override
  _SchoolRegThreeState createState() => _SchoolRegThreeState();
}

class _SchoolRegThreeState extends State<SchoolRegThree> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  SchoolUser schooluser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    schooluser = widget.school.user;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                    child: MyTextFormField(
                      hintText: 'Username',
                      isPassword: true,
                      validator: (String value) {
                        if (value.length < 5) {
                          return 'Username should be at least 5 characters long';
                        }

                        _formKey.currentState.save();

                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (String value) {
                        schooluser.username = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  MyTextFormField(
                    hintText: 'New Password',
                    isPassword: true,
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password should be at least 7 characters long';
                      } else if (schooluser.password != null) {
                        print(value);

                        print(schooluser.password);
                      }

                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String value) {
                      schooluser.password = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          _formKey.currentState.save();
                          widget.school.user = schooluser;
                          widget.onSaved(widget.school);
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Done',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )))
                ]))));
  }
}
```

and finally consolidate the model to a single model class

```
class School {
  String schoolName;
  String schoolPhone;
  String schoolEmail;
  String schoolWebsite;
  SchoolDet address;
  SchoolUser user;
}

class SchoolDet {
  String addressOne;
  String addressTwo;
  String city;
  String pincode;
  String state;
}

class SchoolUser {
  String username;
  String password;
}
```

Comment: How can I change the form in the button tap?

Comment: Please, someone, help me to fix this!!

Comment: I've mentioned the code for the entire thing, can someone look into this and tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Nidheesh to look into this, I really appreciate that. I just wanna ask how'd you mastered java and dart. I'm a python developer and I really love it and I'm trying to get into java and dart. I would like to have a conversation with you asap.
Thanks

Comment: I am from java and it was easy to adapt flutter

Comment: @Nidheesh, have you made any great apps so far?

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use a state management solution like flutter_bloc, provider, etc.

Store it in an array on a different file using state management.

Make the bloc/provider available to all the screens.

You can pass through constructor but I don't recommend that as it will be too messy.